# Image.FromStream - Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, stream

I have list with objects. 
Object has a stream (image i'm loading from website).

When i write:

```
var image1= Image.FromStream(((dane_aukcji)(engine.items[1])).stream);
var image2 = Image.FromStream(((dane_aukcji)(engine.items[1])).stream);
```

first line is working good, and i'm getting correct picture; 
but on second line i get error -   Parameter is not valid

i don't understand - is first line changing a stream ?

Comment: 1. Don't use own language in questions
2. Yes, it does, stream is not a variable. Consider a stream a water in toilet, if you flush it, there can be still water but other water.

Comment: If is a very generic exception and can mean many things.  Swap the two statements.  If the 2nd now works then you know that your program ran out of memory.  If it doesn't then you know it is a problem with the stream content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

It's reading from `stream`. Depending on how your actual *stream* works, you may have to rewind it, set it back to zero position, so the second reader can start from the beginning again.

For example:

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: Thank You very much, but what if straam can't be seek ?

Comment: @barpas Then you don't use it like that. Read the bytes off it first and then use those bytes. If needed, you can always put that data in a new `MemoryStream` to use it as stream, and you can do that as many times as you want, as long as you keep the byte array around.